# Installing unlisted packages and dependency chain quickly

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

There's a few packages I need in 20.04, but it's a massive chain and I don't really want to go through one by one pulling .deb's and installing them

I need Qt 5.15<, extra-cmake-modules 5.70< and KF5 lib 5.80<, any idea on how I can grab all the packages and their dependencies?

They are not available in Focal Fossa repositories

I'm working to install Maui shell on 20.04, https://github.com/Nitrux/maui-shell

Any help would be great and if there's anything I'm missing context wise please comment and let me know and I'll update the question with the info!

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers you can give to get me rolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to carefully inspect their

- repository - here they have interesting file with deb-package dependencies - https://github.com/Nitrux/maui-shell/blob/build-deb/travis-build.sh for automatic build.
- wiki - here they have a guide for Ubuntu - see https://github.com/Nitrux/maui-shell/wiki/Build-instructions-for-Ubuntu.

Good luck!

Comment: Guide for Ubuntu just specifies to obtain the packages and gives a warning about the minimum package version, I'll take a look at that travis context now

Comment: @BrendanJennings It also says to install the extra repository. Also, it says the extra repository isn't necessary for newer versions of Ubuntu. One can only assume that the repository provides the packages needed that are not provided by the standard Ubuntu repositories. Have you tried installing the repository and following through with the instructions?

Comment: That repo didn't contain everything I needed, added everything from the Travis doc and was good thanks!